# How to change the list of events of dynamic type into my own type in calendar in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, calendar

I am using the table calendar for storing the events in the list. The default list is of `List<dynamic>` type but what I want is to store the events in another type list which is of `List<EventStore>` type.
As I change the dynamic to EventStore type, everything goes well. 
And I did it like this, 
  `Map<DateTime, List<EventStore>> _events;` 

But when selecting particular date, it gives the error like, 
`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<EventStore>'`

For showing the list of events for the selected day, I have done this,

```
 onDaySelected: (date, events) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedEvents = events;
                });
              },
```

whereas `_selectedEvents` is `List<EventStore>` type and `events` is `List<dynamic>` type.
**How do I change it to `EventStore` type?**
Have a look to this repo [github repo](https://github.com/amanc1248/conceptualSchoolApp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `Lists` in Dart like so:

```
List<dynamic> data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
List<int> dataAsInts = data.cast<int>();
```

For more information, have a look at the cast() method in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html).

Comment: It is recommended to explicitely declare the type of object while declaration as far as possible. It minimizes run time errors related to object types.